# Visual Basic Value of Query

Tags: vba

Hi i'm a beginner in VB And Access, i was wondering whenever i take the While statement out, it generates a bug, it won't run. 
I think the while statement sets MyList=MyRec[email], is that right?

But why whenever i replace the While statement with only
MyList=MyRec[email], it won't compile.

I'm trying to simplify the code where placing the SQL Statement in MyList
as  MyList=MyRec[email], but i don't know how...

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRec As DAO.Recordset, MyList As String
Set MyDB = CurrentDb
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Select email From TableName")
While Not MyRec.EOF  ' Loop trough the table
MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]
MyRec.MoveNext
Wend
MyList = Mid(MyList, 2)

' use you code here with the mail list ceated

MyRec.Close
MyDB.Close
```

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while is actually looping through all of the items returned into the recordset by the `SELECT` statement.

```
While Not MyRec.EOF                    ' While there are emails still in the recordset
 MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email] ' Append the current email to the list
 MyRec.MoveNext                        ' Get the next email in the list
Wend
```

Without the `While` loop and the calls to `.MoveNext`, you aren't able to retrieve all of the email addresses out of the list.

Make sense?

Comment: Aha Got it, does MyRec![email] do?